# Self join with aggregate query in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have a model class in C# tied to a database with entity framework. In my model I record values for users, and the time when the entry is recorded. What I want is to return a set of entries that represents only the most recent record for a given UserID.

I can accomplish this in SQL with an aggregate query (max date, grouped by user ID) and a self join to match those parameters up with the right record.

```
DECLARE @UserValues
    TABLE
    (
        id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
        UserID INT, 
        Value CHAR, 
        RecordedAt DATETIME
    )

INSERT INTO @UserValues (UserID, Value, RecordedAt) SELECT 3, 'a', '2014-11-06';
INSERT INTO @UserValues (UserID, Value, RecordedAt) SELECT 3, 'b', '2014-11-08';
INSERT INTO @UserValues (UserID, Value, RecordedAt) SELECT 3, 'c', '2014-11-04';
INSERT INTO @UserValues (UserID, Value, RecordedAt) SELECT 5, 'f', '2014-11-03';
INSERT INTO @UserValues (UserID, Value, RecordedAt) SELECT 5, 'h', '2014-11-23';
INSERT INTO @UserValues (UserID, Value, RecordedAt) SELECT 5, 'w', '2014-11-07';

select straight_data.*
from
(
    select UserID          as UserID,
           MAX(RecordedAt) as RecordedAt
      from @UserValues
     group by UserID
) as max_date
join @UserValues as straight_data
  on max_date.RecordedAt = straight_data.RecordedAt
 and max_date.UserID     = straight_data.UserID
```

The result is only the most recent record for each user:

```
id  UserID  Value   RecordedAt
5   5       h       2014-11-23 00:00:00.000
2   3       b       2014-11-08 00:00:00.000
```

See it in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7c4dc/1

So the question is, how do I perform the below operation in LINQ on something like,

```
ICollection<UserValues> MyUserValues;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in linq with these steps :

Group by userId

Order each group by RecordedAt (descending)

Select First from each "group".

```
var dataByUserAndMaxDate = 
    MyUserValues.GroupBy(m => m.UserId)
                .Select(m => m.OrderByDescending(x => x.RecordedAt).First());
```

There's also a `MaxBy` extension method if you use [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) (for linq to objects only)